# Has anybody flown to Diego Garcia to look for MH370?

Tags: mh370

A popular conspiracy theory is floating around that a passenger on-board MH370, named Philip Wood who worked for IBM, managed to stash a mobile phone and [take a black photo](http://intellihub.com/freelance-journalist-hijacked-flight-370-passenger-sent-photo-hidden-iphone-tracing-back-secret-u-s-military-base-diego-garcia/) with the coordinates embedded in the Exif data of where the plane has supposedly landed - a small island called Diego Garcia in the British Indian Ocean.

This is compounded by the fact that the man's wife has [been on BBC News](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S1zNy-5ESos) claiming a cover-up, and also that [the FBI reports](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2584123/Revealed-Malaysian-Airlines-pilot-high-security-US-base-Diego-Garcia-programmed-homemade-flight-simulator-deleted-data-just-taking-control-missing-plane.html) that one of the pilots had been practising flying to Diego Garcia in his home simulator.

It's now been 3 or 4 days since I heard this, and I'm wondering if any agency has been to check it out?

Comment: I realise that I might get blasted for asking this, but I'm interested to know.

Comment: considering what [is known](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/3085/1467) do you really think that they would give credit to easily forged data?

Comment: @falstro The question is whether search & rescue have flown to Diego Garcia. Regardless, I've already flagged it for migration.

Comment: everyone knows it's on the moon. There was even a photograph of it in a UK newspaper! ;)

Comment: This comment in the article is incorrect: "Exif can’t be rewritten with common software, it can only be added to in fields such as image credits with some advanced applications. It can be erased as well but NOT CHANGED" - It's trivial to alter Exif data, it's just text data embedded in the file. There are plenty of applications that will let you edit Exif data, including iPhone and Android phone apps. Anyone could easily insert fake location coordinates and other Exif data into an image file.

Comment: This question has been migarated from aviation.SE. Unfortunately, it isn't an appropriate question here - there's no claim that anyone flew there. The underlying claim (about the conspiracy theory) is already existing, so marking as duplicate.

Comment: Also "The United States Navy operates a large naval ship and submarine support base, military air base, communications and space-tracking facility" on Diego Garcia. There is no need to "fly someone to Diego Garcia" to check whether a large passenger airliner has landed there.